# How to fix feature rotation OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I rotate the existing feature if mouse is over the feature. But the circle has strange behaviour.

https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-forked-nnmo47?file=/main.js

I suppose the problem is in lines:

```
var mouse_x = evt.originalEvent.pageX;
var mouse_y = evt.originalEvent.pageY;
var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - boxCenter.x, mouse_y - boxCenter.y);
```

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: What is your intention/goal for this circle?

Comment: icon rotation should be specified in radians.   If the center of the icon is anchored on the feature it would be easier to use feature and map coordinates to calculate the atan https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-forked-eej1dj